# If a conductor becomes charged will the surface be neutral?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

If an object that is a conductor has a negative or positive charge will the charge redistribute so that the surface of the object is neutral? 
If the surface does become neutral will it be attracted to things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is quite the opposite; usually the charge redistribute itself on the surface and inside the conductor there is no charge. Simply think in this way, if the conductor is charged then the charge carriers because of self repulsion will position themselves as far as possible, that is mostly on the surface.

Comment: In fact if there were charge inside the conductor you wouldn't have a net 0 electric field inside

Answer (score 1):

In that case the charge will distribute in a way to leave the potential constant across the surface. Since some charge was placed in the conductor, it will have a net charge equal to the amount you placed